# How to count downlines in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
$count = 0;
            
            $query =  User::where('sponser_id',$_SESSION['ruserid'])->get();
            //echo count($query);
            $count2=count($query);
            //die();
            $count=0;

            
                foreach($query AS $objChild)
                {
                    $query2 =  User::where('sponser_id',$objChild->sponser_id)->get();
                    $count=$count+count($query2); 
                    echo $query2[0];
                    echo "<br>";
                    echo "====";
                }
            return $count+$count2;
```

How to convert above php code in laravel controller to get downlines?
It run only till first query count.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think the problem comes from the "$_SESSION['ruserid']" , Do you have any error 500 message to share please ? I think you have to replace by something like " Auth::id() " . You can read Laravel Authentification Documentation here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#starter-kits

Comment: I don't have any error for "$_SESSION['ruserid']". It return sponser id.